# YQL is not null is not working

Tags: finance, yql, yahoo-finance

I am trying to fetch stock of which DividendYield is not null.

So, I am querying this statement in YQL Console. The response shows that DividendYield is null. still its returning the value of that stock.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "fb" and DividendYield IS NOT NULL
```

respone does contains `DividendYield: null`.

Here is the response.

```
    ...
    "DividendYield": null,
    ...
```

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22fb%22%20and%20DividendYield%20IS%20NOT%20NULL&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

here is the url for YQL console. Sorry for the formation.

Comment: Not sure if it s datatabbles.org that is down again. I try previous working YQL and it is fail too

Comment: thank you for looking into this. but if i remove `and DividendYield IS NOT NULL` then it is working fine.